# How to I filter out only one combination in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I can't seem to find a question/answer for what I am looking for and it may be that I am just not asking the question correctly. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I have a pandas dataframe and I am trying to get only one of the combinations, I don't care about the order:

```
   ind   col0   
    1    [11908513152, 11646250552]    
    2    [11885390452, 15535908250]    
    3    [11505181152, 16840777350]   
    4    [10939963252, 21451188650]   
    5    [11794522952, 71374807803]  
    6    [11545148452, 19354003650]  
    7    [11849104552, 12114525052]  
    8    [15535681750, 11832504652]    
    9    [13120602349, 11281922352, 17273945153]   
    10   [11281922352, 17273945153, 13120602349]   
    11   [11646250552, 11908513152]    
    ...
```

Line 10 has the same values of line 9, I only want one of them. Same for line 1 and 11.

Comment: Can you put the code the generate this dataframe in this question?  Is that a pd.Series or a pd.Dataframe with one column?  Is that a strings with comma's or is it a list?

Comment: @ScottBoston I think its a pd.Dataframe - the one column contains the list of values as a series. 

```df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, encoding='latin1') for f in all_files)   
concatenated_df   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True, sort=False)   
matched_df.drop(columns=['col1', 'col2'], inplace=True)    ```

Comment: Can you share the data format in the file?

Answer (score 0):

What I will do `split` + `explode` then use `duplicated`

```
s=df.col0
yourdf=df[df.index.isin(s.str.split(', ').explode().duplicated().loc[lambda x : ~x].index)]
                                     xxxxx
0               11908513152, 11646250552  
1               11885390452, 15535908250  
2               11505181152, 16840777350  
3               10939963252, 21451188650  
4               11794522952, 71374807803  
5               11545148452, 19354003650  
6               11849104552, 12114525052  
7               15535681750, 11832504652  
8  13120602349, 11281922352, 17273945153
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert and I am getting `NameError: name 's' is not defined` I know I have to loop through each of the rows in the Series but I don't know how to at the moment. I'll try to work it out.

Comment: Thank you for the update, getting a further error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'`

Comment: @ashley might you have forgotten the `()` in `explode()`?

Comment: Please see the image I just added above. I think I am getting it right, is there a typo I can't see?

Comment: Please help get me there - its so close - the output you have is exactly what I am looking for. But when I run this on the dataset it only gives me the first entry of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get @YOandBEN_W answer to work, although I am very grateful for the help. A big shout out to one of my friends (https://stackoverflow.com/users/12567056/ishan-patel) who sent me this:

```py
import pandas as pd

my_data = {'col0':[ [0, 1.5], [2, 3], [1.5, 0]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)
out = df.col0.apply(lambda x: frozenset(x))
out.drop_duplicates()
```